# How does the Mean Value Theorem translate to higher dimensions?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

For $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $(x,y) \in (\mathbb{R}^2)^2$ we have:

$|f(x)-f(y)| \leq ||x-y||^2$

I'm trying to prove that $f$ has to be a constant function.  My instinct would be to divide one of the $|x-y|$'s to the other side and use the mean value theorem to argue that the derivative has to be zero at every point.  However, I'm unclear on whether the mean value theorem would work here, since $f$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Would it still work as normal, or do I need to change my approach?

Comment: Are there any other conditions on f?

Comment: There aren't, which I suppose means that the mean value theorem might not even work here?  In which case I'm truly stuck.

Comment: If you plan on using MVT you’re assuming continuity on the closed interval $[x,y]$ and differentiable on the open interval $(x,y)$..

Comment: I think $f$ defined by $f((a, b)) = a$ (projection onto the $x$-axis) gives a counter-example to what you are trying to prove.

Comment: You make a fair point, which concerns me because this is a problem on my homework which does not allow for a counterexample.

Comment: Apologies: my proposed counter-example is wrong: I was missing the power of two on the right-hand side of the inequality. Some condition (like continuity) is required as you can easily construct discontinuous counter-examples (e.g., by taking $f(x, y)$ to be 0 for all but two points $X \neq Y$ say and then taking $f(X, Y) = \|X - Y\|^2$).

Answer (score 1):

Take a unit vector $u$. Define $\phi(t)=tu$, for $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and $g=f \circ \phi$.

Then $|g(t)-g(s)|=|f(\phi(t)) - f(\phi(s))| \le |t-s|^2$.

So $g$ is differentiable and $g'=0$ everywhere. That means $f$ is constant at the line generated by $u$. Since all these lines cross at $0$, $f$ must be constant everywhere.